# SetBool and SetTrigger not work on UI button click in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, animation

Hello friends i am having a problem in unity ui button i used the SetBool in a function and also i used the SetTrigger in each function now when i call that function with the keyboard keys it is working but when i use the ui buttons and even if i use the on click or OnPointerUp and OnPointerDown methods which are available in event system the ui button is not working and also there are no console errors. I have also searched many websites but many of the peoples asked for this problem years ago and it was not solved. Also my project is going to build for android. Kindly Help me in this problem. I was also having this problem in my old projects.

Comment: Are Debug.Logs inside the button's On Click event called?

Comment: Yes debug.log also works inside the button on click event called.

Comment: How do you know that the `SetBool` and `SetTrigger` are not working and the issue is not something else? Have you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong here. For using ui button events you should have a reference to the script in your scene and drag and drop the scripts from scene to the button event.
[image]

Now your public functions is available for use.
Also you can post some pictures and code to make your problem clear.

Comment: Hello sir i have already done this but cannot work